# Fitting a complex model of variance-vs-mean for quasi likelihood models? (in R)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, overdispersion, quasi-likelihood

I wish to deal with over dispersion of a Poisson model.  Negative binomial (glm.nb), and quasi likelihood models (family=quasi in glm) do not offer a flexible enough structure of the variance-vs-mean relationship.  I would like to fit a full third order model between mean and variance, and could not find an R function that allow that.  Does it exist?

Thanks.